# Google Apps Script - Automated email based on dropbox option + Adding Indian holidays through script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is it possible to send automated email (Email recorded while submitting Google form) based on the dropbox option (i.e Approved or Rejected). As well is it possible to add indian holidays in the script. So, while calculating leaves the total number of leaves will skip indian holidays.

I'm trying to automate the Leave Form response which will send the mail to the leave applier with the "Approved or Rejected" status.

Thanks!

Comment: Create a separate question for #2

Answer (score 0):

You can send emails from onFormSubmit using the new row data.